# Real analysis- open and closed set

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I just signed up on this website because I can't find the way to solve these questions anywhere.

> Let $( ℝ , d)$ be a metric space , where $d(x,y)=|x-y|$ , $∀ x,y ∈ ℝ$.
>
> Show that the singleton $\{x\}$ is closed set.

Comment: Did you try to show that $\mathbb{R} - \{x\}$ is an open set?

Comment: I think you should include your thought on this. What have you tried? Do you have an approach? Do you know what you need to prove? Etc?

Comment: Skyking i tried to show that the is an x belong to the set x , and its neighborhood is also in the set x , I really don't know if that is even the right way

Comment: How can i show that R - {x} is an open set ?

Comment: @ShouqHere: you seem to be a bit confused. In order to show that the set is closed, try to prove it's complement is open. You can do this by picking a point in the complement and to show that there is some open neighborhood of that point completely in the complement. Hint: use the metric you have to compute the distance between $x$ and the chosen point in the complement and use this to define a suitable radius of the open neighborhood.

Comment: How can i prove that the complement is open ?

Comment: @ShouqHere: This is what's in my comment :)

Comment: I know the the regular definition of closed and open set? What is the deference between it and the one you are talking about ?

Comment: @student so i first pick a point and let it belong to the complement? Like x for example?

Comment: @ShouqHere: Perhaps you should add in your question what definition of open and closed you are using. + You should prove for every point in $\mathbb{R} - \{x\}$ that there is some neighborhood completely in this set. Hence you should prove this for every point not equal to $x$!

Comment: This is the open ball definition B(x,r) ={x belong to E : d(x,a) less than  r }

Comment: @ShouqHere: and your definition of a closed set? Is it the complement of an open set?

Comment: And the closed ball  B(x,r) ={x belong to E : d(x,a) less than  or equal to r }

Comment: How can I know if it the complement of an open set ?

Comment: @ShouqHere: No need to feel this way, we are here to help you. However, note that not all open sets (and not all closed sets) are open balls (respectively closed balls). So have you seen the definition of an open set and a closed set? (Set being more general then 'ball')?

Comment: @student iam so sorry am not really any good at math i hope you can help

Comment: For all x belong to W , there is epsilon grater than zero , B(x, epsilon) subset of W ..... is that it ?

Comment: @ShouqHere: I will post an answer and you can already have a look at the other answer to see if those help you/give you an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We want to prove that $\{x\}$ is a closed subset of the metric space $(\mathbb{R}, d)$. This is equivalent with proving that the complement (= $\mathbb{R} - \{x\}$) is an open set.

In order to prove that $\mathbb{R} - \{x\}$ is open, consider an element $y \in \mathbb{R} - \{x\}$. In particular, we have that $x \neq y$. We want to find an open ball of some radius $r$ with center $y$, say $B(y, r)$ such that $B(y,r) \subseteq \mathbb{R} - \{x\}$. In particular, this means that $x \not\in B(y,r)$ which is equivalent with $d(x,y) \geq r$.

Since you have a metric, we can measure the distance between $y$ and $x$ and since $x\neq y$, this distance will be strictly larger than $0$, that is
$$d(x,y) > 0.$$ 
Now consider the open ball $B(y, \frac{d(x,y)}{2}) = \{z \in \mathbb{R} \vert d(y,z) < \frac{d(x,y)}{2}\}$. It is clear that $x \neq B(y,\frac{d(x,y)}{2})$ since $d(x,y) > \frac{d(x,y)}{2}$. Hence the set $\mathbb{R} - \{x\}$ is an open set, so $\{x\}$ is a closed set.

$\textbf{REMARK}$: we could have considered $B(y, d(x,y))$ and we still would have that $x \not\in B(y, d(x,y))$, however, I really wanted to make it clear to you that you can find an open ball around $y$ not containing $x$.

Comment: In the question he wants us to prove that the set is closed and in the first line you say that {x} is a closed SUBSET ، is that the same?

Comment: And way you say that x dose not equal to y ?

Comment: @ShouqHere: saying that $\{x\}$ is closed is equal to saying it is a closed set, just a matter of giving it a name :) For your question about $x \neq y$: we have that $y \in \mathbb{R} - \{x\}$! The set $\mathbb{R} - \{x\}$ is the set of al real numbers with $x$ thrown out.

Comment: And around y do yo mean that the you donate the center by the letter y ? Can I write any other letter?

Comment: With around $y$, I initially meant that $y$ is an element of the open ball. However, we can pick it as the center, so perhaps I should edit this. You can write every letter you want, except for $x$!

Comment: From [this means that x dose not belong to the open ball ....... which is equivalent with d(x,y) grater than .... I don't understand this part

Comment: I suggest you draw this on a piece of paper: Draw a circle with center $y$ and some radius $r$ and take a point $x$ outside this circle. What can you say about the distance $d(x,y)$? :)

Comment: @ShouqHere If $x$ was in the set then $d(x,y)$ would be less than $r$. But it isn't so therefore $x$ is not in the open ball.

Comment: @ShouqHere: Drawing things always helps me understand them, so perhaps it might be helpful to you too :)

Comment: @ShouqHere: Is the rest of my answer clear to you or would you like some more clarifications?

Comment: You didn't edit the y , could you

Comment: Am just taking a second check

Comment: @ShouqHere: edited

Comment: @Student $B(y,\epsilon)=\{z: d(y,z)<\epsilon\}\neq \{z: d(y,z)<\frac{\epsilon}{2}\} $

Comment: Am sorry but did you edit the y ? It didn't change it says that tou edited

Comment: When you said with center y did you mean did you mean the y that belong to the complement?

Comment: @user160110: thanks, I first wanted to write it using just $\epsilon$, but changed my mind and did not adjust it everywhere.

Comment: @ShouqHere: $y$ is in the complement of $\{x\}$ as I wrote in my answer.

Comment: When you told me about the drawing thing , why did you say that the x is outside the circle?

Comment: @ShouqHere: since you asked me why $x \not\in B(y,r)$ implied that $d(x,y) \geq r$ and $x \not\in B(y,r)$ means that $x$ is not in the circle.

Comment: I didn't understand that distance measuring

Comment: Why is the distance equal to epsilon?

Comment: You want to find the radius of an open ball with center $y$ such that this open ball is in $\mathbb{R} - \{x\}$, so you want to be sure that $x$ is not an element of the open ball. Therefore, you should make the radius of the ball smaller than the distance between $y$ and $x$. (That's why I wrote $x \not\in B(y,r)$). The $\epsilon$ is just because I wanted to give the radius a name and in these kinds of proofs, $\epsilon$ is the most used name. You can give it any other name, as long as it does not confuse you or the reader.

Comment: Can't i just not but the distance measuring part in the solution? It's more complicated

Comment: @ShouqHere: I have no idea what you mean with that last comment... Do you find it more complicated that I denoted the distance by $\epsilon$? If so, I can change all $\epsilon$ by $d(x,y)$ if this is easier to you.

Comment: That would be nice , cause i don't understand you you said that the distance equal to epsilon

Comment: @ShouqHere: it is really just a name to avoid denoting $d(x,y)$ everywhere... Anyway, I have edited it (note that the notation gets much heavier).

Comment: Ok , why is B(y, epsilon /2 ) ? Why is epsilon divided by 2 ?

Comment: What do you mean by the notation gets much heavier ?

Comment: @ShouqHere: Pleas look at my remark in my answer: I did not need to divide by $2$, but I still did, since this makes it much clearer that $x$ is not an element of the open ball that I constructed. I could have divided by any number less than $1$.

Comment: I really hope the rest of my answer is clear to you, since I have to leave now. If it is not clear, I am really sorry, but I will not be able to answer your questions for the next 21 hours.

Comment: Okay , why did did but the d(x,y) instead of r

Comment: This really is my last answer: I first denoted the radius in general by $r$. For the proof, I fix a specific radius, which was $\frac{d(x,y)}{2}$ and no other number than that one.

Comment: Okay, what is z ؟

Comment: @student and what is d(y,z ) my last question

Comment: Am really sorry but these are reallllllllllyyyy my last 2 Question, it would be super helpful

Comment: @ShouqHere: It is just the set notation: the elements in $B(y, \frac{d(x,y)}{2})$ are precisely those elements which have a distance less than $\frac{d(x,y)}{2}$ to $y$. So the $z$ is just introduced to denote all the elements satisfying the condition on the distance. (I denoted the elements in this set by $z$, you by $a$ in your answer to my question on how the open sets are defined, see comments on your question).

Comment: You mean the open ball definition?

Comment: @ShouqHere   That is what I mean :)

Comment: @ShouqHere do you have any more questions?

Comment: I still can't get the last part , if you say that you denoted it by z and i denoted it by a , that mean it should be B(y,d(x,y)/2) ={a belong to R :d(y,z) less than d(x,y)/2 }

Comment: @ShouqHere it is just a letter, i could have written $a$. The only thing which matters in set notation is the condition under which elements are or aren't elements of that set. So if I wrote $a$ instead of $z$, it should be $\{a \in \mathbb{R} \vert d(x,a) < \frac{d(x,y)}{2} \}$ for it to make sense!

Comment: @Student it's just confusing me, can I write it the way i did

Comment: @ShouqHere sure, but then you should change all $z$ into $a$. Perhaps you should review some of your set-theory... Specifically the part about set-builder notation... It are just letters, you can change them as you want, but you should be consistent in your notation :)

Comment: @Student clear ! Can I upload a picture in here ? I want to show you the complete solution, if you are okay with that

Comment: @ShouqHere i think it is only possible if you specified that you wanted to answer your own question.

Comment: @ShouqHere you can also make a new question and use the proofverification tag. However, mathstack users do not really like pictures, so it might be worth it to learn to use mathjax. (It's the way questions are normally typeset on this site.)

Answer (score 1):

A metric space is often imagined as a box with a lot of points in it.

[image]

Where each pair of points has a distance assigned to it $d(x,y)$. The distance is assumed to be positive and only zero when $x=y$(aka if you have different points their distance is positive).
[image]

Along with a notion of distance comes a notion of neighboorhoods or open balls. An open ball $B(x,r)$ is simply the set of points $z$ in the space that have distance $d(x,z)$ less than $r$. 
[image]
An open set is a set $V$ with which for every point $x$ in $V$ you can find an open ball of $x$ contained inside of $V$.
[image]
Closed sets $C$ however are defined to be the sets that contain all of their limit points. In the picture the black area around C is also meant to be apart of it. Limit points of $C$ are points that always have an open ball "touching" $C$. So if a point isn't a limit point it has an open ball that doesn't touch $C$. 
[image]
Also note that since every limit point is in $C$, any point **not** in $\color{red}{C}$ () or **is** in $\color{blue}{R/C}$ has an $\color{purple}{\textrm{open ball}}$ not "touching" $\color{red}{C}$
[image]

With all that said. Assume we don't know that $\{x\}$ is closed but want to show that it is closed (I have drawn the set $\{x\}$ as a white circle containing $x$). We need to show that every point $y$ $\color{blue}{\textrm{outside}}$ of $\{x\}$ has an $\color{purple}{\textrm{open ball}}$ that doesn't "touch" $\{x\}$. Since for any singular point $y$ outside $\{x\}$ we know the distance between $x$ and $y$ we simple make an $\color{purple}{\textrm{open ball}}$ around $y$ with radius less than half the distance between $x$ and $y$.
[image]

Comment: Can I ask you what program you have used to make these pictures? Btw, thumbs up for the clear explanation (altough I am not sure if the OP already knows what limit points are).

Comment: @Student ms paint

Comment: Very nice, vizualising always helps, it makes things very clear :)

Answer (score 0):

In order to show the set $\{x\}$ is closed, one way to do is to prove the complement is open or to prove for each $y \notin \{x\}$, $\exists $ $\epsilon(y)$ such that $\{x\} \cap (y-\epsilon(y),y+\epsilon(y))= \phi$ .

So given any $y \in  \mathbb{R} \setminus \{x\} $, pick $\epsilon = d(x,y) > 0$, and so the open ball of radius $\epsilon$ centred at $y$ contained in $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{x\} $.

Comment: What dose R/ x mean ?

Comment: @ShouqHere: it is another notation for the set of real numbers not containing $x$.

Answer (score -1):

[image]

Is it correct ? @Student If not what to change?